# JSR-303 How to validate two children objects differently

Tags: java, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I'm using Hibernate Validator as JSR-303 implementation.

Suppose I have:

```
class Form {
    @Valid
    private Owner mainOwner;
    @Valid
    private Owner secondOwner;
    // ... many other fields
}

class Owner {
    @DriverLicenseValid // some custom validation
    private String driverLicense;
    // ... many other fields
}

// ...

Form myForm;
validator.validate(myForm);
```

See, I want to validate the whole form, it contains two similar child objects of type Owner. Problem is that for mainOwner driverLicense should be @NotNull while for secondOwner it should be @Null.

I can't use groups here (can I?) since the whole model is checked by a single validate() call. Is there any way to solve this without writing this rule as a custom constraint on the Form level?

Answer (score 0):

Create a validation annotation on the `mainOwner` field in `Form` that validates that the `Owner` instance has a set driver license.

The `@DriverLicenseValid` annotation should just follow the suggestions from the jsr-303 spec that `null` values are valid by default. So you don't need to change the `Owner` class.

Comment: Thanks, but I was asking whether this could be achieved without custom constraint on the Form level - i.e. above mainOwner field. Perhaps I failed to express this properly. However since you are proposing the same solution I thought myself of, I think there is no other way. Ok, surely ScriptAssert would do, but it is almost the same as writing custom validator.

Comment: @RodionGorkovenko I can't think of any other reasonable way to do this. So you should stick to your first thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

If you work with Hibernate Validator 4.x, you could use a custom group sequence provider as described in this [forum post](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=1025406).

Comment: Could you please explain how I can use it for this case. If I annotate  Owner class, then I'll get only link to Owner instance in the getValidationGroups method. I could not tell by this instance is it referenced by mainOwner or secondOwner. If I annotate Form itself - I could not understand what it gives for validation of Owners at all. I'm sorry for my stupidness.

Comment: You would have to past the state/role to the `Owner` instances, e.g. like so: `private Owner mainOwner = new Owner("main");`. Then, in the default group sequence provider you could access the role and return the right default group sequence.

Comment: Ah, thanks. though it is definitely not what I want. Anyway thanks for useful info.

Comment: Yes, it's surely not perfect. Note that as of Bean Validation 1.1, you'll be able to address the issue very elegantly using [group conversions](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/#constraintdeclarationvalidationprocess-groupsequence-groupconversion).

Answer (score 0):

Use groups:

```
class Form {
    @Valid
    @ConvertGroup(from=Default.class, to=NotNullDriversLicense.class)
    private Owner mainOwner;
    @Valid
    @ConvertGroup(from=Default.class, to=NullDriversLicense.class)
    private Owner secondOwner;
    // ... many other fields
}

class Owner {
    @Null(groups = NullDriversLicense.class)
    @NotNull(groups = NotNullDriversLicense.class)
    private String driverLicense;
    // ... many other fields
}

interface NullDriversLicense {}
interface NotNullDriversLicense {}

// ...

Form myForm;
validator.validate(myForm);
```